# Flask Celery No result backend configured

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm trying to use celery 3.1.17 with flask but i'm stuck with a "No result backend configured" error. 
I'm new to both flask and celery so probably i'm doing something wrong.
If i use [this](https://github.com/thrisp/flask-celery-example/blob/master/settings.py) code everything goes fine, but as i split the code into different files i get that error. I'm missing something but what?
I'm using Flask-Script to run the app with "manage.py runserver", files structure is:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── core.py
│   ├── extensions.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── manage.py
└── settings.py
```

With settings.py - just settings

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = 'not_a_secret'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
```

manage.py - runs the applicationn

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell, Server

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("runserver", Server(host="0.0.0.0", port=5032))


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app)
manager.add_command('shell', Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

app/**init**.py: creates app and make_celery as [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/) say

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import celery, make_celery
import settings


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(settings)
    make_celery(app, celery)

    from .core import core as core_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(core_blueprint)

    return app
```

app/extensions.py: instantiates celery and define simple task

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app, celery):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'], broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    print 'passo da make_celery'
    return celery


celery = Celery()

@celery.task(name="tasks.add")
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

app/core.py defines two routes: one for run the task and one for get the result

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, abort, jsonify, request, session
from app.extensions import add

core = Blueprint('core', __name__)

@core.route("/test")
def hello_world(x=16, y=16):
    x = int(request.args.get("x", x))
    y = int(request.args.get("y", y))
    res = add.apply_async((x, y))
    context = {"id": res.task_id, "x": x, "y": y}
    result = "add((x){}, (y){})".format(context['x'], context['y'])
    goto = "{}".format(context['id'])
    return jsonify(result=result, goto=goto)


@core.route("/test/result/<task_id>")
def show_result(task_id):
    retval = add.AsyncResult(task_id).get(timeout=1.0)
    return repr(retval)
```

After launching `celery -A app.extensions.celery worker -l debug` I can go to /test but then if I try to go to /test/result/ i get the following error:

```
  File "/virt/biscelery/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/virt/biscelery/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 597, in _is_disabled
    'No result backend configured.  '
NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

Why celery loose the backend configuration?
If i modify in celery/backends/**init**.py the get_backend_cls function from

```
def get_backend_cls(backend=None, loader=None):
    """Get backend class by name/alias"""
    backend = backend or 'disabled'
    loader = loader or current_app.loader
    aliases = dict(BACKEND_ALIASES, **loader.override_backends)
    try:
        return symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
    except ValueError as exc:
        reraise(ValueError, ValueError(UNKNOWN_BACKEND.format(
            backend, exc)), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

to

```
def get_backend_cls(backend=None, loader=None):
    """Get backend class by name/alias"""
    backend = backend or 'amqp'
    loader = loader or current_app.loader
    aliases = dict(BACKEND_ALIASES, **loader.override_backends)
    try:
        return symbol_by_name(backend, aliases)
    except ValueError as exc:
        reraise(ValueError, ValueError(UNKNOWN_BACKEND.format(
            backend, exc)), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Everything start working again. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.
Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Just checking: have you installed and start your Redis server? If so, you also should add the URI to it (`redis://localhost:6379/0`) in your settings, right?

Comment: @cuducos i'm using rabbitMQ both as broker and backend not redis.

Comment: did u find the work around?